# What are some good free parsing programs?

Tags: java, python, parsing

Are there any good free parsing programs out there in Python or Java?

I have been using a lot of textfiles recently and they are all different. I have been spending a lot of time writing code to parse these textfiles. I was wondering if there is some program that could get all the names of a person out of a textfile or parse the file based on a keyword.

Comment: What is it exactly that you want to parse?

Comment: Depending on what file format you want to parse e.g. XML, HTML, plain text, you may need to use different mechanisms.

Comment: I am dealing with plain text.

Comment: _How_ do you want to parse it?  You may want show samples as well as what you want to do in the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[ANTLR](http://www.antlr.org/) is pretty popular and even has an IDE to help you develop / test your grammars.

Answer (score 4):

Pyparsing is a good Python add-on module for plain text.  Easy to get something going quickly, but has enough supporting components to do some pretty elaborate parsing work.  See http://pyparsing.wikispaces.com, and check out the Examples page.  (Plus it is very liberally licensed, so there are no restrictions or runtime encumberances.)

Comment: Pyparsing is no longer hosted on wikispaces.com. Go to https://github.com/pyparsing/pyparsing

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [JavaCC](https://javacc.dev.java.net/).

From the [JavaCC FAQ](http://www.engr.mun.ca/~theo/JavaCC-FAQ/javacc-faq-moz.htm):

> JavaCC stands for "the Java Compiler
>   Compiler"; it is a parser generator
>   and lexical analyzer generator. JavaCC
>   will read a description of a language
>   and generate code, written in Java,
>   that will read and analyze that
>   language. JavaCC is particularly
>   useful when you have to write code to
>   deal with an input language has a
>   complex structure

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for something like [Apache Lucene](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucene).

Check this: http://lucene.apache.org/java/docs/index.html

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you need to parse.

If you need to solve a particular problem domain then the best way is to create a [domain-specific language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain-specific_language) and [parse it in Groovy](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/docs/latest/html/documentation/core-domain-specific-languages.html).

Answer (score 0):

If the text has a known format, a grammar parser might be your best bet.

[Gold Parser](http://www.devincook.com/goldparser/) is open source and has both Java and Python support, among others.

Comment: Goldparser is nice but it is extremely slow. Even in speed optimized C++ code it takes 10 seconds to parse a 15000 lines of code. If you compare this with the speed of the PHP parser this is extremely slow.

Answer (score 0):

[Lepl](http://www.acooke.org/lepl) is a general-purpose, recursive descent parser for Python that I maintain.

It's similar to pyparsing, in that both are parsers that you write directly in Python. Here's an example that parses and evaluates an arithmetic expression:

```
>>> from operator import add, sub, mul, truediv

>>> # ast nodes
... class Op(List):
...     def __float__(self):
...         return self._op(float(self[0]), float(self[1]))
...
>>> class Add(Op): _op = add
...
>>> class Sub(Op): _op = sub
...
>>> class Mul(Op): _op = mul
...
>>> class Div(Op): _op = truediv
...

>>> # tokens
>>> value = Token(UnsignedFloat())
>>> symbol = Token('[^0-9a-zA-Z \t\r\n]')

>>> number = Optional(symbol('-')) + value >> float
>>> group2, group3 = Delayed(), Delayed()

>>> # first layer, most tightly grouped, is parens and numbers
... parens = ~symbol('(') & group3 & ~symbol(')')
>>> group1 = parens | number

>>> # second layer, next most tightly grouped, is multiplication
... mul_ = group1 & ~symbol('*') & group2 > Mul
>>> div_ = group1 & ~symbol('/') & group2 > Div
>>> group2 += mul_ | div_ | group1

>>> # third layer, least tightly grouped, is addition
... add_ = group2 & ~symbol('+') & group3 > Add
>>> sub_ = group2 & ~symbol('-') & group3 > Sub
>>> group3 += add_ | sub_ | group2

... ast = group3.parse('1+2*(3-4)+5/6+7')[0]
>>> print(ast)
Add
 +- 1.0
 `- Add
     +- Mul
     |   +- 2.0
     |   `- Sub
     |       +- 3.0
     |       `- 4.0
     `- Add
         +- Div
         |   +- 5.0
         |   `- 6.0
         `- 7.0
>>> float(ast)
6.833333333333333
>>> 1+2*(3-4)+5/6+7
6.833333333333333
```

The main advantages of Lepl over pyparsing are that it's slightly more powerful (it can compile itself to regular expressions in places for speed, handle left recursive grammars, uses trampolining to avoid running out of stack space). The main disadvantages are that it's younger than pyparsing, so doesn't have the same number of users or as large and supportive a community.